# Converting to async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have following code

```
function someHelper(someList) {
  return someList.map((item) => {
    return (next) => someService.firstCall(paramForFirst, (err, result) => {
      if(err) next(err);
      else    someService.secondCall(paramForSecond, result, next);
    })
  });
}

module.exports = {
  doSomething(param, callback) {
    async.parallel(someHelper(someList), callback);
  }
};
```

How I can convert second return of `someHelper` function to use `async.waterfall`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I have. Pass the `next`(callback) from parallel and then call methods in waterfall array list and finally call the `next` at the end. By defination `waterfall` will call callback with result or error.

```
function someHelper(someList) {
  return someList.map((item) => {
    return (next) => {
      async.waterfall([
        async.apply(someService.firstCall, paramForFirst),
        async.apply(someService.secondCall, paramForSecond)
      ], next);
    }
  });
}
```